# Leaflet angularjs on zoomend rootscope not changing

Tags: angularjs, maps, leaflet

on map zoomend I am trying to call a function which sets the $rootscope to some value. If I am trying to call the same function directly or through different function it is setting the $rootscope. I am able to see the changed value of rootscope variable in console.log but it is not reflecting on html

```
map.on('zoomend',function(e){
    if(map._zoom<11){
        clearVillageLayer();
    }
});

function clearVillageLayer(){
    setSummaryData("Summary");
}

function setSummaryData(loc){
    $rootScope.rwsSummaryData = data[loc];
    console.log($rootScope.rwsSummaryData);
}
```

the data variable is already set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `$apply` every time you do some manipulations width scope outside of angular (like in leaflet handler). Like this:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function(loc) {
  $rootScope.rwsSummaryData = data[loc];
  console.log($rootScope.rwsSummaryData);
});
```

You need this, to tell angular that scope is updated, so it could run `$digest` cycle, and update the view.